# How to solve StackOverflowError with nested ArrayLists?

Tags: java, android, memory, arraylist, stack-overflow

I'm running my project on some Android devices, and I'm getting errors that I *think* have to do with nested ArrayLists.

Here's the basic setup - I have a figure made up of limbs (think of them as nodes). Each node can have more children nodes and so on and so on. So, each `Node` class has a member `ArrayList<Node> childrenNodes` containing any number of children `Nodes`.

I can't exactly pinpoint why things go wrong, but after adding ~220 nodes in succession to each other (essentially creating a long string of connected nodes), the app crashes.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(9299): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 674
E/AndroidRuntime(9299): Process: __, PID: 9299
E/AndroidRuntime(9299): java.lang.StackOverflowError
E/AndroidRuntime(9299): at __.Node.getSelectedNode(Node.java:283)
E/AndroidRuntime(9299): at __.Node.getSelectedNode(Node.java:273)
E/AndroidRuntime(9299): at __.Node.getSelectedNode(Node.java:273)
E/AndroidRuntime(9299): at __.Node.getSelectedNode(Node.java:273)
...etc
```

The function `Node::getSelectedNode` iterates down the tree of nodes, originating from the main node, to find which one is being clicked, it looks like this (stripped of unrelated code):

```
public Node getSelectedNode(float x, float y)
{
    Node node = null;

    // First look through children (look at front-most child first, the last one).
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    for (int i = _childrenNodes.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        node = _childrenNodes.get(i).getSelectedNode(x, y);

        if (node != null)
            break;
    }

    // If still not found, check this node.
    // ------------------------------------
    if (node == null)
    {
        // if (this node is being clicked) {
        node = this;
    }

    return node;
}
```

So I guess when I call this function, the Stack gets filled up with a ton of calls to getSelectedNode() depending on the number of descendents a node has, leading to a StackOverflowError?

Is that right? If so, I really don't know how to go about fixing this, should I not be using an ArrayList?

Any advice appreciated!

---

**Edit: Here's another scenario I've found that causes a StackOverflowError, when I clone one of these figures (which essentially iterates through each of the Nodes and clones them). Again, the issue seems to originate from a `Node` with too many levels of children, grandchildren, etc...**

I'm also 99% sure there are no cycles, as I've tested for it, this issue doesn't occur with lower number of nodes, and doesn't happen at all on the desktop (at least not with this amount of nodes, probably more).

```
public Node(Node parentNodeRef, Node cloneFrom)
{
    // This constructor is used when cloning a Node.
    this._parentNodeRef = parentNodeRef;

    this._x = cloneFrom._x;
    this._y = cloneFrom._y;

    // ...more cloning of members here, etc...
    // this below is the problematic code, if there's too many children of children of children, etc (I got up to about 220) - I get the error

    _childrenNodes = new ArrayList<Node>(cloneFrom._childrenNodes.size());
    for (int i = 0, numChildren = cloneFrom._childrenNodes.size(); i < numChildren; ++i)
        _childrenNodes.add(new Node(this, cloneFrom._childrenNodes.get(i)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have a _cycle_ of `Node`s?  That is, a node `a` has `b` as one of its children, which has `c` as one of its children, which has `a` as one of its children.

Comment: @rgettman - I thought of that, but no, that's definitely not the case, I've run tests to make sure.

Comment: If you do not have a circular reference, and you truly have enough nodes to fill up the stack, then there is probably a better way to model your data.  What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Your code never uses `x` and `y`.  (Passing them to a recursive invocation of itself doesn't count, because the recursive invocation won't use them either.)  What were you thinking was going to happen with those parameters?

Comment: How confident are you that you don't have a circular reference? I find it really hard to believe that you are getting a StackOverflow without a circular reference.

Comment: By the way, the way your function works currently, it will only ever return the first leaf it encounters unless it encounters the correct node on that path. You immediately return "this" when the for loop exits.

Comment: I'm 99% sure there are no cycles. I've edited my main post with another scenario that produces the StackOverflowError, cloning a Node that has too many generations of children Nodes attached to it, as Robin pointed out below, I believe this error is due to "excessive deep recursion." I don't know how I'd go about getting around this issue, though, especially with the cloning.

Comment: in `getSelectedNode`, you never actually test the node.

Comment: I removed unnecessary code from the getSelectedNode function to make it clearer as to what it does, not so much how it does it (really just cut out some distance x/y testing), I made it clearer in the OP.

Comment: You said you're using 220 nodes; if they were all tied together in a single path, *maybe* you would have excessively deep recursion. But I just don't think you have enough nodes for it to be excessively deep, *especially* considering that your original function will terminate recursion after encountering a single leaf node.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of recursion, use a code defined stack or queue and a while loop.

```
queue q = new queue()
q.push(root)
while not q.empty()
      node = q.pop()
      for each child of node
           q.push(child)
      //perform some code on current node
```

Answer (score 0):

> The most common cause of stack overflow is excessively deep or infinite recursion. Languages like Scheme, which implement tail-call optimization, allow infinite recursion of a specific sort—tail recursion—to occur without stack overflow. This works because tail-recursion calls do not take up additional stack space.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow

getSelectedNode calls itself in the forloop, which will call itselg again and again and again...

Comment: It's good to see it written out bluntly like that, "excessively deep recursion." That's what I suspected, but I don't know how I'd get around it. I edited my main post with another scenario (cloning the figure, thus cloning the nodes that make up the figure - too many generations of nodes on one node creates this "deep recursion" when I clone it).